# reactjs switch custom themes doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, themes

I have three basic custom themes and I want to switch between them.

I have some problems/ questions:

1. Why the container from CustomToolbar.jsx is "working" but the container from Component1.jsx not?
2. Why the button from App.js is changing background and the button from components not? ( also it should)
3. Sometimes when I click multiple times on buttons from CustomToolbar i have an error :

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `theme` is marked as required in `ThemeProvider`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in ThemeProvider (at CustomThemeProvider.js:37)

    in CustomThemeProvider (at src/index.js:11)
```

I don't know how to manage them, and any help how to improve the code would be great.

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cache-s92ez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1 and 2**: It's because you are wrapping each of your components inside `ThemeProvider`/`MuiThemeProvider`, doing that will override your custom theme.

Wrapping your `App` inside `CustomThemeProvider` on your index.js is enough.

---

**Question 3**: `e.target.innerHTML` will *not always* return the text inside the button when clicked. Try console logging that then click the button but not on the text, you'll see something like

```html
<span class="MuiButton-label">red</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"><span class="MuiTouchRipple-ripple MuiTouchRipple-rippleVisible" style="width: 128.825px; height: 128.825px; top: -35.4127px; left: -8.41273px;"><span class="MuiTouchRipple-child MuiTouchRipple-childLeaving"></span></span></span>
```

To fix that you can use `e.currentTarget.textContent` instead.

Please check the demo below.

[image: Edit busy-saha-8rjrc]

Comment: Great answer. One more question, if I have a table or more inside component1 and I want to override the tablecell/ tablerow separately for each one (each table has different tablecellstyle), how to do that? I need to wrap every table in <ThemeProvider theme={theme_table1}>  and define a custom theme ?


`let theme_table1 = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiTableCell: {
      color: "#ff0000"
    }
  }
});
`

Comment: Yep, if you want your components to have different theme you can do that. I think `makeStyles` is also an option.